# Calendar App with Colored Events from Google Calendar?

Tags: sync, evolution, calendar, google-calendar

I use colors to categorize events in my Google Calendar. This is very handy in a browser and on my Android phone.

Alas, when viewing events from a Google calendar i Evolution, events are no longer colored except for the color of the entire calendar itself.

Are there any calendar applications for Ubuntu that can sync with the event colors from Google calendar?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Gnome Calendar, it syncs with Google Calendar.

> sudo apt-get install gnome-calendar

It should be installed by default in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Alas no. It allows for different colors for calendars, but no per-event settings.