# Any calendar app that supports multiple types of events and can filter them for year view?

Tags: calendar

Any calendar app  that supports multiple types (tags) of events and can filter them for year view?

I've noted gnome-calendar does not mark days with events on 'year' view. Nor does it have types of events to filter with.

Any calendar app for Linux that has those? There is no answers to related [Calendar App with Colored Events from Google Calendar?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815774/calendar-app-with-colored-events-from-google-calendar), but it was 7 years ago, maybe things changed (at least knowledge about rare apps became more widespread).